# different constructs of inline English yields different fonts in polyglossia

Tags: fonts, polyglossia

I'd like to use the English font when interleaving English with Hebrew (the latter is the main language). It appears however that the Hebrew one is used, as shown by this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=hebrew, numerals=arabic]{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David CLM}

\begin{document}
אבג English דהו

אבג \begin{english}English\end{english} דהו
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like the font used in the second line (default English one) to be used also in the first line without having to start a new environment (also there appears to be extra spaces because of it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without the environment you get the `\hebrewfont` (and David CLM has the glyphs for the latin alphabet). However the `english` environment is best used between paragraphs. For inline inserts you can use `otherlanguage*` or `\foreignlanguage`:

```
אבג \begin{otherlanguage*}{english}English\end{otherlanguage*} דהו
אבג \foreignlanguage{english}{English} דהו
```

Of course you can define your own abbreviations, for instance

```
\newenvironment{english*}
  {\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}}
  {\end{otherlanguage*}}
\newcommand{\EN}{\foreignlanguage{english}}
```

so that you may type

```
אבג \begin{english*}English\end{english*} דהו
אבג \EN{English} דהו
```

Reserve the `english` environment for insertion of whole paragraphs.